# Can't import a complete url into an url field with feed-me

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

#### Description

I have a JSON feed which contains an external URL like "https://example.com" *(entries/external_link/url)*.
There is no error in feed-me logs when I run it, all the text data and assets are imported without any problems. Except for my URL field. I get "[ ]" instead of "https://example.com".

Any help on this ?

#### JSON exemple

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": "140",
            "type": "regular",
            "title": "Banner import title (fr)",
            "subtitle": "Banner import subtitle (fr)",
            "body": "<p>Banner import body&nbsp;(fr)</p>",
            "internal_link": [{
                "type": "node",
                "title": "test",
                "id": "6",
                "cta": "Banner import link text (fr)"
            }],
            "external_link": {
                "cta": "Banner import link text (fr)",
                "url": "https://example.com"
            },
            "images": [{
                "url": "",
                "caption": ""
            }],
            "placements": [],
            "postdate": "2019/12/10",
            "status": "1"
        },
    ],
    "nextPage": "",
    "length": 20,
    "totallength": 23
}
```

#### Additional info

- Plugin version: 4.1.2
- Craft version: 3.3.17

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make `external_link` an array?

```json
"external_link": [{
    "cta": "Banner import link text (fr)",
    "url": "https://example.com"
}],
```

Comment: Yes I did try that but I've got the same result... Anyway thanks for your answer.